# Can we add multiple relationships between two classes in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

If I have two classes, and two types of relationships exist between them -- for example composition and dependency -- what shall we do? Do we add two relationship symbols between classes?

Example: Suppose the first class is `BookFestival` and another class is `Book`. `Book` has method register for the festival:

- 1st relationship: composition if there is no book then no Book festival
- 2nd relationship: Dependancy if we change Festival conducting date it affects the book class

Answer (score 2):

If you'd have 10 different kind of relationships between two classes, you could show all the 10 relationships **if these are useful**.

Take for example  `Book` and `Author`:

- A book can have several authors, and an author can write/contribute to several books. This is a many-to-many association.
- At the same time `Book` may have an operation to add an `Author` to its list. So there is a `«use»` dependency from `Book` to `Author`.

We could in theory, indicate the two relationships.  However, when there is an association we assume that there is a dependency:  even without the operation, the `Book` needs to know about its `Authors`.  In practice we do not indicate explicitly such an implicit dependency.

Take as another example `Employee` and `Department`:

- A `Department` has several `Employee` that have the role of `member` of the department.
- A `Department` has also one `Employee` that has the special role of `manager`.

We would indicate the two relationships since both correspond to a different kind of relationship and none implies the other.

A last important remark: use composition scarcely. In your example, the `BookFestival` is not made of `Books` and the books exist without `BookFestival`. Moreover books could be presented at several festivals. THis means that there is no exclusive ownership, of books by festivals and hence, no composition.  Conversely,  a `Book` is not made of `BookFestivals`, and a book festival is about more than one book.  THis means that there is no exclusive ownership in the opposite direction  Hence no composition between the two.

Answer (score 2):

To ammend Christophe's answer:

> for example composition and dependency

In that case it's simple: a dependency is the weakest relation between classes. Anything stronger just inherits the dependency. So if you have a composite aggregation it will include the dependency and you do not need to show it again. You could do so but it would simply be pointless.